# Include in .net Application Setup File .. SQL SERVER 2005 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

My application required SQL SERVER 2005 Express edition.
So how can I make the application setup to include SQL setup and run behind setup.

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click your Setup Project and select properties.
2. Click "Prerequisites"
3. Select the the prerequisite you need - in this case SQL Server 2005 Express
4. Either select "Download from the component vendor's web site" or if you are going bundling the setup with your own installation then select "Download from the same location as my application"