# How to add database and crystal report yo windows form application so it can be deploy to client pc

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I have created a winForm app in vs15.
But the problem is that i am not able to install it on client side.. 
My app contains a database on sql server 2012 and a crystal report..
It works well on my pc but not on client.. 
Kindly any one may help me in this problem.
It is more convenient to me if step by step procedure provided. 
Thanks in advance.. 
Ask me about my problem if there is any misunderstanding or vagueness in my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include in .net Application Setup File .. SQL SERVER 2005 Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545799/include-in-net-application-setup-file-sql-server-2005-express)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Clickones to create a installer for your programme :

Have a look at this :[link](http://www.craigbailey.net/vsto-deployment-via-clickonce-screencast/)

[image]

And also you can InstallShield : 
Under Other Project Types you should see Setup and Deployment.
you can get the installer extension [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)